# two forms one submit button javascript

Tags: javascript, forms

Not able to submit these two forms with a singe submit button. I tried to use javascript but didn't work.

Can anyone please help me with this?

```
            <form id="batting" name="form1" method="post" action="">
            <input type="checkbox" name="batsman[]" value="1" /> <?php echo $bat1; ?><br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="batsman[]" value="2" /> <?php echo $bat2; ?><br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="batsman[]" value="3" /> <?php echo $bat3; ?><br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="batsman[]" value="4" /> <?php echo $bat4; ?><br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="batsman[]" value="5" /> <?php echo $bat5; ?><br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="batsman[]" value="6" /> <?php echo $bat6; ?><br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="batsman[]" value="7" /> <?php echo $bat7; ?><br /><br />
            </form>

            <form id="bowling" name="form2" method="post" action="">
            <input type="checkbox" name="bowler[]" value="1" /> <?php echo $bow1; ?><br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="bowler[]" value="2" /> <?php echo $bow2; ?><br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="bowler[]" value="3" /> <?php echo $bow3; ?><br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="bowler[]" value="4" /> <?php echo $bow4; ?><br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="bowler[]" value="5" /> <?php echo $bow5; ?><br /><br />
            </form>
            <input type="button" value="Click Me!" onclick="submitForms()" />

            <script type="text/javascript">

            //Syntax: checkboxlimit(checkbox_reference, limit)
            checkboxlimit(document.forms.batting, 2)

            //Syntax: checkboxlimit(checkbox_reference, limit)
            checkboxlimit(document.forms.bowling, 1)

            submitForms = function(){
                document.forms["form1"].submit();
                document.forms["form2"].submit();
            }

            </script>
```

Comment: You can only submit one form at a time, not two. You can however make two ajax requests or join the data and send it once with ajax.

Comment: @adeneo - why not? think you can..#

Comment: Think about it. Form submission means that page reloads, browser starts loading new resource, new URL, etc. How do you think is it possible to load two pages at the same time in one tab?

Comment: If you think you can, and that the rest of the world is wrong, why not get it working and show us how ?

Comment: okkk but i don't know how to use ajax. can anyone help?

Comment: You can submit two forms, so long as they don't target the current window (or if you don't care about the response, which is unlikely).  Targeting new windows or iframes would work just fine.